# Django Getting m2m fields old and new value in save

Tags: python, django

I have a model that where I want to keep track of the changes whenever the fields have been updated/edited. So every time before I save the new update, I will get the old and new values and create a new Audit object to keep track those changes.

Tried the method below which works for most fields except m2m relationship fields (such as User) where it both the old and new values remain the same. Are there anyway I could get the old and new m2m field values so that I can create a record of Audit every time the Model object is saved/updated?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.old_name= self.name
    self.assigned_users = self.assigned_users.all()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    audit = audit.objects.create(
        old_name=self.old_name,
        new_name=self.name.
        old_assigned_users=self.old_assigned_users,
        new_assigned_users=self.assigned_users.all())

    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```